# Cython C++ templates problems

Tags: cython

This is my C++ code

```
/**
 * A CSI data format converter
 * @tparam OutputValueType
 * @tparam InputValueType
 * @param inputArray
 * @return
 */
template<typename OutputValueType, typename InputValueType>
static std::vector<std::complex<OutputValueType>> convertCSIArrayType(const std::vector<std::complex<InputValueType>> &inputArray) {
    std::vector<std::complex<OutputValueType>> outputArray(inputArray.size());
    for (auto i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
        outputArray[i] = std::complex<OutputValueType>(inputArray[i].real(), inputArray[i].imag());
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```

I want to wrap this function in my cython code,such like this.

```
    cdef cppclass CSISegment:
    std::vector<std::complex<OutputValueType>> convertCSIArrayType(const std::vector<std::complex<InputValueType>> &inputArray)
```

but it is definitly wrong,so how could i wrap this c++ code with template rule ?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed, based on the code you shared, that the function is a public method inside of class called `CSISegment`, which is not a template.  If that is correct, this code would declare the wrapper:

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.complex cimport complex as cpp_complex

cdef extern from "yourcode.cpp":
    cdef cppclass CSISegment:
        @staticmethod
        vector[cpp_complex[OutputValueType]] convertCSIArrayType[OutputValueType, InputValueType](vector[cpp_complex[InputValueType]] &inputArray)
```

Sources:

[workaround for using std::complex in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956131/wrapping-a-function-returning-a-vector-of-complex-types-in-cython)

[templates, c++ standard library in cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#templates)

[static members in cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#static-member-method)